# Apache marmotta installation failing on my Windows 8 Laptop

Tags: tomcat7, apache-marmotta

I was trying to install `Apache marmotta` on my home laptop.. I was able to install the program. But when I'm starting it by clicking the `Start Apache Marmotta` button, I m getting an error like the linked image below.

[image]

The error occurs just before launching the `localhost:8080` page. The program exits if I hit the cancel button.

Does anybody have answer to this?

Is there any other dependency on some other program like `MySql` server or anything?

Comment: I recommend you mention the versions of java, tomcat, marmotta and tag as 'tomcat' or 'tomcat7'. Did you have a working tomcat server before installing marmotta?

Comment: Software versions are like below.  Java- ver 8, Tomcat - (comes with Marmotta) - 7.0. ... I dint have tomcat installed before. What do you mean by tagging as tomcat7?

Comment: Sparql Query Interface page looks like this:  http://marmotta.apache.org/platform/sparql-module.html

Comment: I do not see the error... log appears normal.

Comment: Instead of localhost, what about 10.xxx.yyy.zzz or 192.168.yyy.zzz?  Localhost in Windows 7 and above maybe commented out in your \windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file (edit with notepad or similar)..  And, by the way, do you have anything that maybe over-writing what is in your windows hosts file?  If you use some of the anti-malware programs or if you have been infected by malware, the hosts file can be a target.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my case:

Solution:

Just disconnect the internet and so it would begin to work properly subsequently.

Sorry for my English.