# Apache Marmotta - SPARQL query interface - Missing Squebi library

Tags: sparql, rdf, linked-data, apache-marmotta

Those who have hands-on knowledge of Apache Marmotta use in Windows environment, please help me!

I have installed marmotta on my Windows 8.1 env. Now as we know, marmotta supports a RDF framework (where sparql is used as the query language), and we have a jar-library to make sure the Query interface runs correctly. (Jar file name - squebi-1.0.1.jar, can be found in the webappps folder under apache marmotta installation directory).

Now my question is very straightforward. How will I make my Spqrql query interface run in marmotta?? As I'm getting a "loading" dialog box for ever. See the linked image below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZfRUw.jpg

I got some help from this site: https://github.com/tkurz/squebi#queryparams--object. So changed the dependency statement in the pom.xml file. Still the loading window is not getting over.

What I need to do to let my query interface run normally, and I can do some experiments ??

This question is somewhat related to my earlier question:
[Apache marmotta installation failing on my Windows 8 Laptop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29713543/apache-marmotta-installation-failing-on-my-windows-8-laptop)

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Sparql Query Interface page looks like this:  http://marmotta.apache.org/platform/sparql-module.html  

But the loading window is not disappearing at all in my machine. It seems to run for ever. Do anyone know a solution to this? Any dependency file which I have to add ??

Answer (score 0):

That bug ([MARMOTTA-614](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MARMOTTA-614)) is already fixed in squebi `1.0.3` and available in the current development version of Marmotta (`3.4.0-SNAPSHOT`).